# Getting TypeError while including multiselect option using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the following error while trying to integrate angular multiselect.

> Error:

**TypeError: _.contains is not a function**

I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example14data" selected-model="example14model" checkboxes="true" extra-settings="example14settings"></div> <pre>Selected Model: {{example14model}} | json</pre>
    </div>
```

Here suppose user clicked on drop down list and then clicked on outside to close that list or get back to normal state of the list at that time this type error is coming in console.

My controller side code is given below.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.example14model = [];
    $scope.example14settings = {
        scrollableHeight: '200px',
        scrollable: true,
        enableSearch: true
    };
    $scope.example14data = [{
    'id':1,
    'label':'aaa'
  },{
    'id':2,
    'label':'bvc'
  },{
    'id':3,
    'label':'rtcv'
  },{
    'id':4,
    'label':'uytg'
  }
  ];
    $scope.example2settings = {
        displayProp: 'id'
    };
});
```

That opened drop down list also not closing after click on outside.My [Total code is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/VqUhPLNQXqhxgMjbbW0E?p=preview). Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the lodash version. You have used a version that doesn't have contains method

Refer this
https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1298

Try using a lower version.